# Construct a space with free involution and homological restriction

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I'm looking for a space $X$ which satisfies the following conditions:

1. $X$ is a compact manifold.
2. $H_\ast (X;\mathbb Z)$, the integral homology groups $X$, are torsion free.
3. There is a free involution $T$ on $X$.
4. $H_\ast (X/T;\mathbb Z)$, the integral homology groups of the orbit space $X/T$, have higher $2$-torsion.

Can you give an example of $X$?

Otherwise, is the following assertion true? If a space $X$ satisfies 1,2 and 3, then the exponent of the torsion subgroup of $H_\ast (X/T;\mathbb Z)$ is always $2$.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "higher 2-torsion"?

Comment: "higher 2-torsion" means a cyclic group of order 2^i for some i ¥geq 2. In other words, I'm looking for a space X such that X/T does not look like a real projective space.